# When adding second axis, line still drags across the bottom despite transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Some data:

```
x <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18779, 18780, 18781, 18782, 
18783, 18784), class = "Date"), Sessions = c(3301L, 2991L, 3310L, 
2604L, 2058L, 2446L), `Site Conversion Rate` = c(0.00939109360799758, 
0.00702106318956871, 0.00362537764350453, 0.01036866359447, 0.0116618075801749, 
0.0147179067865904)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Looks like this:

```
x
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  date       Sessions `Site Conversion Rate`
  <date>        <int>                  <dbl>
1 2021-06-01     3301                0.00939
2 2021-06-02     2991                0.00702
3 2021-06-03     3310                0.00363
4 2021-06-04     2604                0.0104 
5 2021-06-05     2058                0.0117 
6 2021-06-06     2446                0.0147
```

I'd like to plot sessions on one axis and then conversion rate on another. Here's the start:

```
x %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'steelblue')
```

Gives:
[image]

So far so good. Now I want to overlay `Site Conversion Rate`:

```
x %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'steelblue') +
  geom_line(aes(date, `Site Conversion Rate`))
```

Gives this:
[image]

You can see the line across the bottom. I tried to move the line to it's own axis:

```
x %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, Sessions)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'steelblue') +
  geom_line(aes(date, `Site Conversion Rate`)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. / 10000))
```

Gives this:
[image]

The line still drags across the bottom. I tried adjusting the scale `sec_axis(~. / 10000)` adding and removing zeros, but no matter what I try the line always drags across the bottom.

How can I add a secondary axis for the Conversion Rate with it visibly above the flor?

Comment: You have to transform the data as well, e.g. try with `geom_line(aes(date, `Site Conversion Rate` * 10000))`.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work, thanks!